# Best way to set up multiple tableviewcell layouts

Tags: swift

I am in the process of creating a new tableviewcontroller however, I need this to be dynamic in a way that the layouts for each cell could change.

What I mean is that I am parsing news from JSON. Each news item could be of 3 types: Post, achievement, announcement. Each of these types contains different pieces of information. Post would have title, date, image and tags. Announcement would have the same but include an importance label. Achievement will have username, image, date, profile image, social sharing.

The news listing page will display all of the items but ordered by date but the layout for each of the types are completely different.

I have started and successfully got the below working:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if(indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        let cell: NewsPostTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("newsPostTableCell") as! NewsPostTableViewCell
        return cell
    }
    else
    {
        let cell: AchievementCardTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("achievementCardTableCell") as! AchievementCardTableViewCell
        return cell
    }
}
```

to display 2 of the different layouts but I then started thinking, how will I be able to determine in the cellForRowAtIndexPath what layout to apply? Basically in the JSON response there will be a template identifier to notify the app which template to apply but just don't know how to apply this...if possible.

Would it be best to create 3 different view controllers 1 for each of the layouts and embed them?

Comment: How are you storing the posts in your app? Do you just have  the array of dictionaries (`[[String:AnyObject]]`) you got by deserializing the JSON? Or do you convert the JSON to an array of real objects (e.g. Post, Announcement, and Achievement classes you created)? In other words: describe your data model.

Comment: I deserialize the JSON (not converting to real objects).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how you are parsing the JSON you could store the type of cell into an Array.  Then as you look into the array with indexPath.row based on the type it finds there you have it execute a Switch.